# Why does this always return false (nested for loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's pretty simple:

```
var shouldDoThis = function(query) {
    documents.forEach(function(section) {
        section.words.forEach(function(word) {
            if (word.content == query.content) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
};
```

This is a (poorly) reworded snippet - if I pass in a query that should resolve to true, 'return true' gets hit but then jumps right to return false, so this always evaluates to false.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `shouldDoThis` function only has **one** `return` statement - the `return false;`. The `return true;` is inside of a different function that has nothing to do with the return value of `shouldDoThis`

Comment: @Ian I see that, but I'm expecting the shouldDoThis to finish as soon as return true; is hit.  How can that be achieved?

Comment: That makes no sense. Why would that `return true;` affect `shouldDoThis` at all? You need to read about `return` statements, scope, and the `forEach` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are returning false always. `return true` is on other scope.
You should write your code like this:

```
var shouldDoThis = function(query) { // 1st level
    var should;
    documents.forEach(function(section) { // 2nd level
        section.words.forEach(function(word) { //3rd level
            if (word.content == query.content) {
                should = true;
                return; // you "quit" the 3rd level function. This returns to 2nd level
            }
        }); // end of 3rd level
    }); // end of 2nd level

    return should;
}; // end of 1st level
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: Thanks Agustin, this helps a lot.

Comment: Or, since `forEach` is available, the use of `some` makes more sense here: http://jsfiddle.net/EGNgb/

Comment: @RobVious - This looks extremely inefficient... you are going to iterate over (and perform a string comparison on!) every single object in the collection no matter where the match is found. A short-circuit function like [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) would be much better. You'd need to propogate the short-circuit up through the multiple calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to logically break these up, it might make more sense. Although not necessarily JavaScript syntax, imagine this:

```
function shouldDoThis(query) {
    documents.forEach(sectionDo);
    return false;
}

function sectionDo(section) {
    section.words.forEach(wordDo);
}

function wordDo(word) {
    if (word.content == query.content) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I know this wouldn't work in a real situation, but breaking it apart helps separate the idea of having multiple functions within functions. As had been mentioned, the `return true;` statement only applies to the `wordDo` function, not the `shouldDoThis` function.

A good solution could involve returning something from `wordDo`, `sectionDo`, and then checking that in `shouldDoThis`.